# Constraint on cross-reference table that will check primary key table columns for integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints, intersection, cross-reference

I have a cross-reference table which contains two foreign keys. RoleId(PK,FK) and PermissionId(PK,FK). The Role table and the Permission table both contain a foreign key column called ApplicationId. I want to ensure that a record cannot be inserted into the cross-reference table that contains a RoleId associated with ApplicationId 1 and PermissionId associated with ApplicationId 2. Is there any method other than using a trigger to accomplish this type of integrity?

Comment: This is a Business Rule you are trying to implement into your Database, and the only way to achieve this will be using a Trigger, Or if you want to be able to do things manually , You can create a Store Procedure to Insert Data which checks against your rules and adds data valid data or returns a User Friendly message on failure.

Comment: You can add a helper table with two rows then use an indexed view to enforce this. Same idea as my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886657/values-controlled-by-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1):

you can add the applicationId column to the cross reference table and then extend the foreign keys of the Role and Permission tables to include the applicationId column . This gives the desired referential integrity .

Here is a worked out schema in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `application` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `permission` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `applicationId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_app` (`id`,`applicationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_perm_app` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationID`) REFERENCES `application` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `applicationId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_app` (`id`,`applicationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_role_app` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationID`) REFERENCES `application` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `role_permission_application` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roleID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `permissionID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `applicationID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_role` (`roleID`,`applicationID`),
  KEY `FK_permission` (`permissionID`,`applicationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_permission` FOREIGN KEY (`permissionID`,`applicationID`) REFERENCES `permission`  (`id`,`applicationID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_role` FOREIGN KEY (`roleID`,`applicationID`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`,`applicationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I actually ended up going a different route before this answer was made, but +1 for a viable option, once converted to SQL Server. The way I went was to remove ApplicationId from both the Role and Permission tables, and created cross reference tables of RoleApplication_xref, PermissionApplication_xref, and RolePermissionApplication_xref. Once the appropriate foreign key constraints are created, it accomplishes nearly the same task. The main difference being that the base table records aren't tied to ApplicationId. Your suggestion requires less tables, and seems more straight forward. Thanks.