# Unique column value per primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for storing a report template. The report is made up of 1, 2, 4, or 6 different graphs (the scale). There will be a separate row for each graph and each row will contain the number of graphs on the report.

```
CREATE TABLE ReportTemplate (
    TemplateName varchar(100) not null,
    UserName varchar(100) not null,
    GraphPosition int not null,
    Scale int not null,
    -- graph specific stuff here
Constraint PK_ReportTemplate primary key clustered
    (TemplateName ASC, UserName ASC, GraphPosition ASC)
)
```

I have constraints that ensure that Scale is 1, 2, 4, or 6 and that the GraphPosition is <= Scale.

What I want to do, is ensure that for each template (TemplateName/UserName pair) value, all rows have the same value for Scale. I'm wondering how I might do that.

Comment: What do you mean by `... for each primary key value, all rows ...`? For each PK there is exactly one row in the table.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I meant for each unique pair TemplateName/UserName, I want Scale to be the same.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to ensure that all rows which share a `TemplateName, UserName` also have the same `Scale`?

This means your design is not normalised as Scale is functionally dependent on those two columns. So to normalise this you would use a different table with a PK of `TemplateName, UserName` to ensure a single row for each (and a column for the desired Scale) so you only store this fact once.

But with your existing structure you can use an indexed view to enforce this constraint.

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT TemplateName, 
       UserName, 
       Scale, 
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS C
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY TemplateName, UserName, Scale

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON SomeView(TemplateName, UserName)
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, there really ought to be two tables, one for the template and another for the individual graph data. Our current release has a template per graph and we are expanding to have a template that handles multiple graphs. Perhaps we should just bite the bullet and normalize. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Russ Though then you would need a cross table constraint for the `GraphPosition is <= Scale` which would need an indexed view again (could be done something like this approach where you create a query for the condition that should never happen and cross join to a helper table http://stackoverflow.com/a/16886913/73226)